# How to share a mobile folder to access it using local network on PC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, sharing

I'm trying to share a mobile folder using local network on PC.
How to access mobile memory card from PC?

Searching around, I can find the opposite, to access PC folder using mobile.
That's is easy and I can do it.
But how to do the opposite?
How to have the mobile folder tree on Windows Explorer LAN without using USB cable?

Comment: Be more specific: where is "mobile folder"? Different devices have different connection protocols. See your *user manual*.

Comment: Just use USB.  If your mobile device is close enough to use your Wireless, it is close enough for USB. If not on your Wireless, what you want is not likely possible.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, "mobile folder" is at mobile internal memory or sdcard. Goal is to have all its files at local network on PC, as a mapped drive.

Comment: @John, yes, I can use USB. I'm doing so, while I don't know how to use WiFi connection. You'll agree that using WiFi is far better. But I can't see how to do that.

Comment: In a nutshell, you're asking for an Android or iOS APP and there are many to do just that. Now, mobile phones and tablets are off-topic here unless it's about a a physical connection with a PC, not the case here. You may want to do your own search - I'm sure you can easily find many "file server" apps - or ask at Android Enthusiasts or Ask Different.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, my question isn't about Android or iOS APP. I'm not interest to installing one more APP on mobile. I know about AirDroid and many other APPs around. I'm looking for a way to add the mobile files to the local network, natively. I guess, I'm not being off topic here. If there is no way to do what I want, please say so.

Comment: There is no "native" way to do that, there's only software that can do that and in any case it's a MOBILE question - you always have to do something in the server side, anything else in the clients side is trivial - which, again, is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an FTP client and access it via file explorer by adding a network location
some mobile devices have an in-built FTP application so check for that also.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. You could improve your answer by giving an example of such an app.

Comment: Thank you, @Akhil Ashraf. FTP is a kind of solution. I was trying to install SambaDroid or LAN drive - SAMBA Server & Cli, but both aren't on PlayStore anymore. They work on previous Android versions, not 13, my current one. Now, I'm Looking for alternatives.